# overriding operator to concat two byte array

Tags: c#, overriding

i used the following code to concatenate two `byte[]` using override operator `+`.
but there is an error i cannot understand.
here is my method's header

```
public static byte[] operator +(byte[] bytaArray1, byte[] bytaArray2){...}
```

Error text:

> One of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type

how should i implement this?

Comment: Note: if you are doing lots of this, it suggests you should probably be using something like `MemoryStream` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot define an operator for another class.

One alternative would be to create an **extension method** like so:

```
public static byte[] AddTo(this byte[] bytaArray1, byte[] bytaArray2){...}
```

Comment: i was adopted about that. but now i am sure that i cannot do that. also cannot use `public static byte[] operator +(this byte[] b1, byte[] b2) { return null; }`

Comment: i preferred this solution: ``public static byte[] concatByteArray(params byte[][] p)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            byte[] tmp;

            foreach (byte[] item in p)
            {
                sum += item.Length;
            }

            tmp = new byte[sum];
            sum = 0;

            foreach (byte[] item in p)
            {
                Array.Copy(item, 0, tmp, sum, item.Length);
                sum += item.Length;
            }
            return tmp;
        }``

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to create an operator overload inside a class definition which is not of `byte`.

suppose this

```
class Program
{  
 public static Program operator +(Program opleft, Program opright)
 {
    return new Program();
 }
}
```

This compiles fine, because I am overloading operator + for Program and my operands on which I am performing + operations are of type Program too.

Comment: Well, to be more accurate, it's because The operator overload is not inside the class `byte[]`. And since a class cannot have '[]' as part of its name, what Rzassar is asking for is actually impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I preferred this solution:

```
    public static byte[] concatByteArray(params byte[][] p)
    {
        int newLength = 0;
        byte[] tmp;

        foreach (byte[] item in p)
        {
            newLength += item.Length;
        }

        tmp = new byte[newLength];
        newLength = 0;

        foreach (byte[] item in p)
        {
            Array.Copy(item, 0, tmp, newLength, item.Length);
            newLength += item.Length;
        }
        return tmp;
    }
```